# Creating elasticsearch-dsl DocType objects from dict or json

Tags: python, json, django, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using the `elasticsearch-dsl` library to define mappings in `elasticsearch` and to index django model objects. For initial indexing I, however, want to use `json` data for all models. Is there a way to instantiate `DocType` subclass objects directly from `json` or from a python `dict`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do `MyDoc(**my_dict)`